# Trying to build a custom module

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I'm trying to build a simple custom odoo module using python, whenever I try to install it I get this error:

[image]

> XMLSyntaxError: String not closed expecting " or ', line 1, column 18

I don't know what exactly I'm suppose to fix?

Comment: Looks like your XML is invalid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is related to your custom addon's XML file.

The message somehow indicates that the string attribute you have given in your xml file is missing " (double quotes) somewhere.

Check the xml files of your custom modules and try doing that.

eg - issue might be like this -

```
<field name="any_field" string="Any String />
```

The missing " after the string value might be the reason for error. check it and get it done.

Thanks

Comment: i take the code from a website, and they were using `` in place of "
thanks for your help sir